# AWS SNS - Resend Confirmation to Endpoint

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Is there anyway to resend a confirmation to an email endpoint without deleting and recreating the subscription to the topic? I'm trying to handle cases where the user fails to confirm their subscription after three days.

The [API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html) didn't seem to mention anything like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are describing a use case that is not currently supported by Amazon SNS APIs.

Once a subscription enters the **Pending Confirmation** state, there is no way to tell Amazon SNS to attempt to re-send the confirmation message. Therefore, the only viable workaround is recreating a new subscription using the same email address. This doesn't actually result in a separate subscription as it seems that an email address can only be subscribed once. However, it does send another email with a new confirmation link which you can click to confirm the subscription.